# GO_TO_PAGE GOOGLE SHEETS TO FORMS, HOW TO SET GO TO PAGE VARIABLE

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hy everyone,

I'm currently struggling with a problem as the google description is not optimal. I need my code to enter a skip to section 4 if the multiple choice is replied with the answer "yes".

I cant figure out how to add the name of the page to the GO_TO_PAGE variable. if I add GO_TO_PAGE it just skips to the next question.

Any examples on how to go to a section based on the multiple choice answer?

Thanks!!

```
  else if (i =='PAGE') {  
  if (d[x][3] == 'Page1') {var PAGE1 = f.addPageBreakItem(1).setTitle(d[x][1]);}
  else if (d[x][3] == 'Page2') {var section2 = f.addPageBreakItem(2).setTitle(d[x][1]);}
  else if (d[x][3] == 'Page3') {var section3 = f.addPageBreakItem(3).setTitle(d[x][1]);}
  else if (d[x][3] == 'Page4') {var section4 = f.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(d[x][1]);}
  else if (d[x][3] == 'Page5') {var section5 = f.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(d[x][1]);}
  var sectiong = s.getRange(x,2, 1, 1).getValues();
                          
  var cell = s.getRange("B70");
  cell.setValue(sectiong)                        
                          
    row = row +1;
}

else if (i =='CHOICE') {
    var arr = [];
    
  if (d[x][2] = 'CAN YOU MAKE THIS PART?'){
    var pageBreak = f.addPageBreakItem();
    var item = f.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    item.setTitle('CAN YOU MAKE THIS PART')
    var rightanswer = item.createChoice('YES', FormApp.PageNavigationType.GO_TO_PAGE);
    var wronganswer = item.createChoice('NO', FormApp.PageNavigationType.RESTART);
    item.setChoices([rightanswer, wronganswer]);       
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### You need to pass the desired page break instead of `FormApp.PageNavigationType.GO_TO_PAGE`

Sample snippet:

```
var f = FormApp.create('myForm');
var item = f.addMultipleChoiceItem();
var section2 = f.addPageBreakItem()
.setTitle('Page 2');
var section3 = f.addPageBreakItem()
.setTitle('Page 3');
var section4 = f.addPageBreakItem()
.setTitle('Page 4');
var rightanswer = item.createChoice('YES', section4);
```